# Echo boolean field as yes/no or other values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field on a read only SQL table called **attended** can only hold two values either 0 or 1.

This is how I am printing the field at the moment:

```
  echo "<td>" . $row['attended'] . "</td>";
```

It only returns 0 or 1 - the value in the **attended** field. How can I have it return **no** for *0 (i.e not attended)* or **yes** for 1 *(i.e. attended)*.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **ternary operator** (also known as the conditional operator in some languages) `?:`:

```
echo '<td>' . ($row['attended'] ? 'yes' : 'no') . '</td>';
```

This operator is mentioned in the manual page [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) under the heading "Ternary Operator".

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No);

echo "<td>" . $arr[$row['attended']] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Thanks! I kinda like your solution! I use this in my language files to convert a bool to Yes/No.

Answer (score 1):

The [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is a good fit:

```
echo ($row['attended']?'yes':'no');
```

If you want to get yes/no directly from your sql query, use an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) statement:

```
SELECT IF attended THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' AS attended
FROM …
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
echo "<td>" . ( $row['attended'] == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no' ). "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
echo('<td>'.(($row['attended']==1) ? 'yes' : 'no').'</td>');
```