# return mysql boolean as 'yes' or 'no'

Tags: mysql

I have a BOOLEAN type column in my table. I would like to convert the 0/1 to Yes/No when the results are returned.

I found a response on this thread: [Echo boolean field as yes/no or other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547419/echo-boolean-field-as-yes-no-or-other-values)

The response mentioned an IF THEN statement, but when I try, I only get a complaint from MySQL that there is a syntax error. Here is the line I am using:

```
IF qz.quiz_enabled == 1 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' AS enabled
```

Here is the error:

```
use near 'qz.quiz_enabled == 1 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' AS enabled
```

Comment: Can you only use mysql?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
select case when qz.quiz_enabled 
            then 'yes' 
            else 'no' 
       end
```

or

```
select if(qz.quiz_enabled, 'yes', 'no')
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d7150/1)

Comment: That is a great way to do it

Comment: Thanks Juergen D, I used the IF option and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);

IF n > m THEN SET s = '>';
ELSEIF n = m THEN SET s = '=';
ELSE SET s = '<';
END IF;

SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ', m);

RETURN s;
END
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. My mistake, I failed to mention I am using a SELECT statement, not a stored procedure.